# converting string data to file as input argument to an application expecting filepath

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function which returns data as string. This string data I want to convert it to file type data without actually writing into a physical file to provide as argument to an application which expect it as a config file data. how to do this in python?

my sample code snippet is like -

```
tokenStr = get_token(some arguments)
#this tokenStr I want to pass to one application which expect this as a file path
os.system('myapplication --tokenFile ' + tokenFilePath)
```

#this should be my desired result -

```
os.system('myapplication --tokenFile ' + tokenStr_converted_to_filepath_without_writing_physically_to_file)
```

Is there any way this can be done in python3.

please provide any code snippet which can perform such kind of conversion.

thank you for you help and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

you can use Path from pathlib,

```
from pathlib import Path    
path = Path(<your string value>)
```